# Why does this code recreate the same file every time it is run?

Tags: java, file, io

I am trying to create a file named `VirtualATM.txt` in a given directory if it does not already exist, if it does exist it shouldn't do anything to do the file and just continue. I am finding that with my code, whether the file exists or not, it is wiping the data inside the file and re-creating it every time I run it. The code I used to do this is below:

```
try{
        String DirToWriteFile = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/VirtualATM.txt"; //Get path to write text file to.
        DirToWriteFile.trim();
        File file = new File(DirToWriteFile);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
}catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can anyone tell me why this happens?

Comment: `if (!file.exists() && file.isDirectory())` doesn't look right. You're checking whether it doesn't exist **and** is a directory.

Comment: Even when I change that, the file gets re-created every time I run the program...

Comment: That sounds strange, because the Javadoc for `createNewFile()` specifically states: "Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist." The `file.exists()` check is actually redundant.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yeah, I haven't yet completed it, but if it helps to see this piece of code in context, here is a link:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/h3z30vfjw5vszi4/VirtualATM.java

Comment: The issue is with your `FileWriter`, you need to use the constructor that creates an appending `FileWriter`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.io.File,%20boolean)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here

```
if (!file.exists() && file.isDirectory())
```

you are checking that if file exits and it should not be directory. No need for this if you want to just check if file exists

just use

```
if (!file.exists)
```